# Get a popup instead of an iframe when using getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have a map (openlayers) that gives me an iframe of attribute data when a pixel is clicked/ queried. How would I go about having a nice popup window instead of an iframe? My code for the query is:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url = parish.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
              '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
      });
```

The 'info' is from

```
 <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: You can use `window.open()`

Comment: I'd rather it open a pop-up window that a new browser

Comment: What do you mean by "pop-up window"?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Comment: What are the contents of `url`?

Comment: Its a Geoserver hosted map layer that contains the attributes I'd like in the pop up. At the moment it displays in an iframe

Comment: What is the data format of the attributes?